# logfile endpoint in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I read Spring Boot Actuator [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints) and saw `logfile` endpoint mentioned there which would really come in handy.

However this endpoint is not registered in my app and I have no idea how to make it available. What is needed here?

Comment: It looks like they are built in. You can't just hit /log file or /health?

Comment: none worked for me : java 8, 2022, <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/logfile` was included in version [1.3.0+ only](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/LogFileMvcEndpoint.java#L51).

If you use an earlier version it will then not be present..

Answer (score 21):

In order to enable this feature, one of these two params need to be set:

- `logging.file.name`
- `logging.file.path`

[Logging configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-logging-file-output)

After that the endpoint should be enabled by default.

Comment: I saw this in the docs, however I haven't been able to get this to work, either. I have tried in 1.2.5.RELEASE through 1.3.0.M5. Do you have any hints? Have you tried it yourself and observed it working?

Comment: We have been using it for multiple applications, but we set these up approx 9 months ago and I do not remember experiencing any problem with it.

Comment: Probably you should start adding some code and pom.xml etc to this post.

Comment: fyi, I punted on the Spring Boot /logfile endpoint and wrote my own, named '/logFile', so it doesn't collide in case I get /logfile working some day.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. Refer to [EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.java#L179) for spring's conditions for creating the MVC endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I added below code to enable /logfile endpoint

```
pom.xml
-----------

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


application.properties
-----------------------

management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.env.enabled=false
endpoints.configprops.enabled=false
endpoints.autoconfig.enabled=false
endpoints.beans.enabled=false
endpoints.dump.enabled=true
endpoints.heapdump.enabled=true
logging.level.root=info
logging.file=target/app.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had below lines in my application.properties . I am using spring-boot with actuator

```
logging.file.name=./logs/log-file.log
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Without the management extension line, the response was

```
Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Dec 04 05:04:40 IST 2019 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available
```

Answer (score 0):

I had used below for

version 2.1.3 -> management.endpoint.logfile=C:/apps/Benefits-logs/adapt-rest.log
as you can see class **LogFileWebEndpointProperties**

and this also works
logging.file=C:/apps/Benefits-logs/adapt-rest.log

No need to add logging.path. If you see LogFileCondition class you will get to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.5 and using the config server.

Although I noticed that logging.file.name works when the application.properties is embedded in the project, it didn't work when configured in the config server.

I had to use this property:

```
management.endpoint.logfile.external-file=${logging.file.name}
```