# Swagger integration with Logback

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, logback, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm setting up my Spring Boot application and I've managed to add API documentation using swagger following this tutorial
http://heidloff.net/article/usage-of-swagger-2-0-in-spring-boot-applications-to-document-apis/

[image]

It's all good I can see the endpoints and use the UI to hit them. Now I want to add somehow visibility of my logging file. I'm using logback with rolling file appender. Is it possible to configure swagger to start showing my logs?

Comment: "The old version of swagger was able to do that" – could you please elaborate? In what way did old Swagger present you your module's logs?

Comment: @MrMister I was wrong about this claim sorry.

Comment: You can achieve this using springboot, swagger will automatically pick the rest service up. There is an endpoint in boot for logfile. To activate it, you have to add `logging.file` and pass it the location of your logfile and it will start to appear on swagger ui. Similar answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938997/logfile-endpoint-in-spring-boot